# Create a custom view with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, fragment

I'm trying to make a little view in Android Studio that can drag it from right to left. This view will have 2 buttons.

And when you select one of them or press outside of it, the small menu will hide again.

I have been searching and I have not got any library that does something similar. I also have no idea how to do it.

I can draw the small view in a separate view (layout xml) but I don't know how to add it and create the events to be opened or closed by dragging.

[image]

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you try `NavigationView` component?

Comment: not entirely, the view is smaller and contains the icons horizontally. although it behaves similar since it is dragged from one side and must be closed when pressing outside

Comment: I think you can change the size of `navigationView` then define a `relativeLayout` in it that it contains two `button`.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: It is a good idea, i tried the @Lakindu idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic example of creating a custom draggable drawer.

These are the references I went through.

To detect drag / fling gesture I have used GestureDetectorCompat, and 
I referred to : https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector

To create drawer open and close animations I referred to : https://youtu.be/OHcfs6rStRo

Please note that this is a very basic example.
You can use this as the base to create your end goal.
You will have to filter out unwanted drag / fling callbacks you receive.
You will have to ignore the taps that you'll get on the drawer.

Here's the implementation.

MainActivity.java

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;
import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean mIsDrawerOpened;
    private ConstraintLayout mRootConstraintLayout;
    private final ConstraintSet mDrawerClosedConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    private final ConstraintSet mDrawerOpenedConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    private GestureDetectorCompat mGestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer_closed);

        // Drawer is initially closed
        mIsDrawerOpened = false;

        mRootConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootConstraintLayout);

        mDrawerClosedConstraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_drawer_closed);
        mDrawerOpenedConstraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_drawer_opened);

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(
                getApplicationContext(),
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

                        // Drag / Fling gesture detected

                        // TODO: Recongnize unwanted drag / fling gestures and ignore them.

                        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mRootConstraintLayout);

                        // Drawer is closed?
                        if(!mIsDrawerOpened) {
                            // Open the drawer
                            mDrawerOpenedConstraintSet.applyTo(mRootConstraintLayout);
                            mIsDrawerOpened = true;
                        }

                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

                        // Single tap detected

                        // TODO: If user has tapped on the drawer, do not close it.

                        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mRootConstraintLayout);

                        // Drawer is opened?
                        if(mIsDrawerOpened) {
                            // Close the drawer
                            mDrawerClosedConstraintSet.applyTo(mRootConstraintLayout);
                            mIsDrawerOpened = false;
                        }

                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

res/layout/activity_main_drawer_closed.xml

```xml
<ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootConstraintLayout"
    android:clipChildren="false" >

    <ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="108dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notch"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:src="@drawable/drawer_notch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/drawerConstraintLayout" />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

res/layout/activity_main_drawer_opened.xml

```xml
<ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootConstraintLayout" >

    <ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="108dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notch"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:src="@drawable/drawer_notch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/drawerConstraintLayout" />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

res/drawable/drawer_notch.xml

```xml
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

app/build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        .
        .
        .
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Result :

[image: Result]

Comment: Excellent, it worked correctly for me. You just have to indicate that the following must be added to the Main_Activity.xml: `<include layout="@layout/activity_main_drawer_closed" />`. Thank you @Lakindu

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you. In this example, the layout resource used for `MainActivity` is `activity_main_drawer_closed.xml`. You can see it in `onCreate` method. There's no `main_activity.xml` here. Yes, you can have a `main_activity.xml` and include `activity_main_drawer_closed` layout inside it if you want.

Comment: Hi @Lakindu, i had a problem with old Android's versions (for example, Versión 21). The drawer Open layout doesn't show, only the notch. can you emulate it and see what's going on?
 Thx.

Comment: @KrmX, Yes you are correct. I can see that when I run it on an Android L emulator.
`TransitionManager` API is available from API level 14. So, animation should work in level 21 as well. I will look in to it and try to provide you a solution.

Comment: @KrmX, I could not find a way to resolve it. So I posted this issue as a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/61729160/2443657

Comment: @KrmX, you can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61732464/2443657) to resolve the issue. I tested it on both API level 29 and 19, and got the expected behavior on both platforms. I edit this answer to include that fix.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add android `material` dependency in your `Gradle` :

```
implementation  'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Then you can use `NavigationView` component like this :

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navi_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="btn1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:text="btn2" />


</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

**This is very simple example without convention , you should improve it.**