# UI components not visible in TransitionManager animations

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-transitions

This is an issue in a Java Android application with a very simple custom draggable drawer in MainActivity.

This is how it behaves when it runs on Android 10 (API level 29) emulator, and it is the expected behavior.

[image: draggableViewApi26]

But the problem is, when it runs on Android L (API level 21) emulator, it behaves unexpectedly as follows :

[image: draggableViewApi21]

During the animation, UI components are not visible. But when app goes to background and comes back, they become visible.

Implementation details of app :

To detect fling / drag touch gesture, `GestureDetectorCompat` was used.
When a fling gesture is detected, the custom drawer open animation is being initiated.
Animation is implemented using `ConstraintSet`, `ConstraintLayout` and `TransitionManager`.

This is the implementation of touch gesture detections and TransitionManager animations.

MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean mIsDrawerOpened;
    private ConstraintLayout mRootConstraintLayout;
    private final ConstraintSet mDrawerClosedConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    private final ConstraintSet mDrawerOpenedConstraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    private GestureDetectorCompat mGestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer_closed);

        // Drawer is initially closed
        mIsDrawerOpened = false;

        mRootConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootConstraintLayout);

        mDrawerClosedConstraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_drawer_closed);
        mDrawerOpenedConstraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_drawer_opened);

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(
                getApplicationContext(),
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

                        // Drag / Fling gesture detected

                        // TODO: Recongnize unwanted drag / fling gestures and ignore them.

                        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mRootConstraintLayout);

                        // Drawer is closed?
                        if(!mIsDrawerOpened) {
                            // Open the drawer
                            mDrawerOpenedConstraintSet.applyTo(mRootConstraintLayout);
                            mIsDrawerOpened = true;
                        }

                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

                        // Single tap detected

                        // TODO: If user has tapped on the drawer, do not close it.

                        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mRootConstraintLayout);

                        // Drawer is opened?
                        if(mIsDrawerOpened) {
                            // Close the drawer
                            mDrawerClosedConstraintSet.applyTo(mRootConstraintLayout);
                            mIsDrawerOpened = false;
                        }

                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

This is the layout XML of closed drawer.

res/layout/activity_main_drawer_closed.xml

```xml
<ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootConstraintLayout">

    <ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerConstraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        <!-- Constraint start (left) of drawer to end (right) of parent (drawer is outside the parent) -->
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        ... >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="1"
            ... />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="2"
            ... />

    </ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notch"
        android:src="@drawable/drawer_notch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/drawerConstraintLayout"
        ... />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the layout XML of opened drawer.

res/layout/activity_main_drawer_opened.xml

```xml
<ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootConstraintLayout">

    <ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerConstraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        <!-- Constraint end (right) of drawer to end (right) of parent (drawer is inside the parent) -->
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ... >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="1"
            ... />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="2"
            ... />

    </ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notch"
        android:src="@drawable/drawer_notch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/drawerConstraintLayout"
        ... />

</ConstraintLayout>
```

ConstraintSets from those 2 layouts are taken as start and end key-frames for animations.

Min SDK version is set to API level 19.

build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Full implementation can be found in [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/lakinduboteju/1a0661a562edcf8cec28377ae1860d74).

Comment: I created this simple custom draggable drawer as my answer to a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61618992/2443657). The asker pointed out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/109155732) issue in my answer, and I could not find a way to resolve it. So with this question I ask for help from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this works as expected you need to add `android:clipChildren="false"` to your root `ViewGroup` in your case is `ConstaintLayout` in your layout `activity_main_drawer_closed.xml`. Of course such solution applicable only when your view is outside of the viewport.

I don't know why this behaviour differ through versions of Android. In theory, from Android Marshmallow, when you start scene transition root view became invalidated by `TransitionManager` and being redraw.

Comment: **It worked! You are awesome!**
If you can recommend any resources that we can read to understand the internal workings of `TransitionManager` or about Android transition in general, please comment them here. Thank you very much.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know such resources. When I impact such issues on my way as Android developer, I google answer, there is nothing special. And of course I use official documentation as starting point of any research. And yes, I understand, sometimes it's hard to achieve an answer to issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, Thank you for answering the question and resolving the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Lakindu for your help!!! НиколайГольцев thx too... Good Job...